# Style Binding not updating with template structure [Vue]

Tags: vue.js

In my example I want to draw a border around an element after clicking on it. In this example it works perfectly:

```
<div v-for="(parent, index) in $store.getters.getInfo" :key="index">
    <div @click="setClicked" :id="child.id" v-for="child in parent"
         :style="[child.clicked ? {'border-color': 'black'} : {'border-color': 'white'}]">
    </div>
</div>
```

But when i try with a bit more complicated structure and template tags the style binding fails to be triggered:

```
    <div v-for="i in 12">
      <template v-for="(user, index) in $store.getters.getSharedUsers">
        <div :id="child.id" v-for="child in $store.getters.getSharedInfo[user[0]][i-1]" 
             :userID="child.userID" @click="setClicked"
             :style="[child.clicked ? {'border-color': 'black'} : {'border-color': 'white'}]">
        </div>
      </template>
    </div>
```

In my mutation I set the attribute with:

```
Vue.set(state.element_map[payload.uID][payload.dID], 'clicked', true);
```

When I debug I see the change in both code examples in my data structure after calling the setClicked function, but only in the first one the style binding is triggered and the border is drawn. The only difference I see is the use of the template tag and the more complicated data structure. But it should also work in the second example as the clicked attribute is set correctly. So what am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: why are you using another template inside one template?

Comment: Ah yes, thank you. the second one is redundant, edited it. But the problem still exists.